# What chargers are compatible with A1226?

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe

I need to buy a power supply for my A1226 15-inch Macbook Pro (2007), but I can't find any anywhere. Apple's online store, ebay, or amazon. So I'm wondering if the charger doesn't have to be the one for your specific model. I found [this charger](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Genuine-Apple-60W-MagSafe-Power-Adapter-for-MacBook-and-13-Inch-MacBook-Pro-/171023290404#shId) that says that it's for Macbooks and 13-in Macbook Pros. It's 60W, so I'm guessing that it'll work. Will it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [your mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp13) you'll need a 85W power adapter [like that one](http://store.apple.com/fr/product/MC556Z/B/adaptateur-secteur-magsafe-de-85%C2%A0watts-dapple-pour-macbook%C2%A0pro-15-et-17%C2%A0pouces?fnode=5a).

Comment: Maybe that's why I've melted three 60W chargers.

Comment: That's very likely.